# Я, а скорее мой брат(,) тебе поможет

Tags: запятые

Мне, кажется, что 81-й пункт здесь: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123 —противоречит тому, что в самом конце — 2-й пункт — написано здесь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118.

Какие запятые нужны?

> Мой кот, именно мейн-кун(,) любит лёжа есть.

> Мой кот, а именно мейн-кун(,) любит лёжа есть.

> Этот фрукт, вернее ягода(,) очень вкусна.

> Этот фрукт, а вернее ягода(,) очень вкусна.

> Я, скорее мой брат(,) тебе поможет.

> Я, а скорее мой брат(,) тебе поможет.

Comment: Я(помогу). А скорее мой брат тебе поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Вводное слово** ***А СКОРЕЕ*** при **однородных** отношениях:

(1)  *Я, **а скорее**, мой брат можем тебе помочь.*

Также: *Мой брат, **а скорее**, его друг могли бы тебе помочь.*

**Розенталь.** **Вводное** слово выделяется запятыми.

(2) *Я, **а скорее** мой брат можем тебе помочь.*

Также: *Мой брат, **а скорее** его друг могли бы тебе помочь.*

**ПАС под ред. Лопатина.** Вводное слово используется в значении **союза.**

Сказуемое согласуется с однородными подлежащими **во мн. числе.**

**Кстати, о правилах.**

Мне вариант в ПАС в случае однородных отношений представляется **неудачным**. Вводное слово может **дифференцировать** однородные отношения, **оставаясь** вводным словом. **Грамматическая** функция у Розенталя обозначена четко, как и в современной грамматике. Это **общий принцип** решения задач для вводных слов не только в этой теме.

Поэтому заменять вводное слово ***А ИМЕННО*** союзом ***А ИМЕННО*** нет никакого смысла.

Answer (score 1):

(1) *Мой кот, **именно мейн-кун,** любит лёжа есть. Мой кот, **а именно мейн-кун,** любит лёжа есть.*

(2) *Этот фрукт, **вернее ягода,** очень вкусен. Этот фрукт, **а вернее ягода,** очень вкусен.*

(3) *Я, **скорее мой брат**, вот кто тебе поможет. Я, **а скорее мой брат**, вот кто тебе поможет.*

**Примечание:** ***вот кто*** — для согласования со сказуемым.

**Пояснение**

**[А ИМЕННО](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_13&layout=item)**  А. Вводит в предложение пояснительные члены – слова или словосочетания, которые конкретизируют то, о чём говорится до союза. Пояснительные члены предложения, присоединяемые союзом «а именно», **обособляются.**

**[ИМЕННО](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_236)**  2. Союз. Вводит в предложение пояснительные члены – слова или словосочетания, которые конкретизируют то, о чём говорится до союза. Пояснительные члены предложения, присоединяемые союзом «именно», **выделяются (или отделяются)** запятыми.

Comment: Вот за это плюс.

Comment: Только во втором-то полное несогласование! *Этот фрукт очень вкусна.* А как же то, что у Лопатина в примерах дано?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр: «_Только во втором-то полное несогласование! Этот фрукт очень вкусна._» === Тем не менее этот ответ _**с полным несогласованием**_ два плюса уже успел получить. О чём это может говорить?

Comment: Ах, моя невнимательность, извините.  К тому же все внимание  от всех участников досталось брату.  Вот об ЭТОМ и говорит. ( Я вас, кстати, не минусовала, не в моих это правилах.)

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр: У Лопатина однородные отношения, в этом случае они с Розенталем действительно не согласны. Розенталь отдельно обособляет вводное слово. (Но на практике обычно пишут по Розенталю.) У нас же обособленный уточняющий оборот, в этом случае вводные слова будут относиться к обособленному обороту у всех авторов.

Comment: Sharon: «_Ах, моя невнимательность, извините_».  === Sharon, я не о Вашей ошибке – ошибиться может каждый! Я  – о голосующих. Вместо того чтобы прочитать ответ и сообщить его автору  об ошибке (для её исправления) — то ли голосуют, не читая ответ, то ли…  

Comment: Шило на мыло! Теперь пунктуация правильна, но звучит всё ужасно, т. к. слово *ягода* ближе.

Comment: Может быть, надо *Этот фрукт, а вернее, ягода очень вкусна*?

Comment: Шило на мыло! Убираем вводное слово. Этот фрукт, ягода очень вкусна. Звучит ужасно.  Предлагаю: Этот фрукт, ягода вернее, очень вкусен.  Ягода на втором плане (вставочная интонация), незаметно будет!  Agree, sir.

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант:

***Я… а скорее, мой брат тебе поможет.***

Comment: Случайно изменил, залагало немного.

Comment: @Максим: _Случайно изменил, залагало немного_. ===  А минус-то тоже случайно поставили? А если не случайно, так хоть бы объяснили, за что: ведь использование многоточия после «Я» действительно позволяет сохранить авторский текст без добавления каких-то лишних, **не сказанных автором слов** «для согласования со сказуемым».